# Adding Bootstrap only to Specific Components in Angular (version 13)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, single-page-application

My problem is that I have a project in Angular 13 (current latest) and I need to add the Bootstrap framework only to a specific set of components in this project.

Is there any chance I can link it on a per component basis?

**Expected Question**

*Why don't I add Bootstrap to the whole project?*

This project is a migration of an existing no frameworks or libraries website only using plain HTML-CSS-JS of small-medium scale. The time for migration is very limited (so little time in fact that I have plain JavaScript in my component.ts files). I also am not familiar with Angular, first time starting such sized project with any front-end web framework in fact.

**Chosen Answer**
Initially, I did choose to add bootstrap per component and referencing it from my assets' folder. However, after the input of a fellow user about view encapsulation leading to terrible performance consequences, I did manage to update the given CSS code to be compatible with a global integration of the Bootstrap 5 framework. I recommend others just fix compatibility if possible as well due to the performance issues. I used the package from NPM if anyone is curious `ng add bootstrap`. I can confirm that also the CDN from Bootstrap also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save Bootstrap css file in `assets` folder and add the path in component `styleUrls`.

My folder structure is -

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ app
│  ├─ assets
```

Include CSS path in component -

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
     './test.component.css',
     '../../assets/bootstrap.min.css'
  ],
})
```

Comment: It worked. I got the minified CSS Bootstrap file from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/. Nicely done.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that this will replicate the entire bootstrap css framework for each component you're importing the css file in (while encapsulating the styles).

Answer (score 1):

Download the bootstrap css file and save it in your assets folder. Then include it in the `styleUrls` array of your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
     './test.component.scss',
     '/assets/bootstrap.min.css'
  ],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Comment: Sounds great. I will give it a go shortly and see if it works.

Comment: cdn url not working -`Failed to compile. HostResourceResolver: could not resolve https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css in context of path to component.ts)`

Comment: Yeah, it seems the CDN link is not recognized for me either.

Comment: Then you should download the css file, save it in your assets folder and point the component to that file. I updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

Importing `bootstrap.css` in each component that needs to be styled will cause the entire bootstrap css file to be replicated in the bundle for each component, while encapsulating the styles.

On the other hand, you could for example import the `card.scss` in your custom `CardComponent`. But when you  have a component that must consist of multiple components working together (for example **navbar** which consists of **navbar-item**s and **navbar-dropdown**s, you'll end up in a situation as such:

```
.navbar[ng_scope1] {
    /* Expected style for the navbar */
}

.navbar[ng_scope2] .navbar-dropdown[ng_scope2] {
    /* Expected style for the navbar-dropdown */
}

.navbar[ng_scope3] .navbar-dropdown[ng_scope3] .navbar-item[ng_scope3] {
    /* Expected style for the navbar-item */
}
```

Since your html is something like

```
<bs-navbar>
    <div class="navbar" ng_scope1>
        <bs-navbar-dropdown>
            <ul class="navbar-dropdown" ng_scope2>
                <bs-navbar-item>
                    <li class="navbar-item" ng_scope3>Login</li>
                </bs-navbar-item>
            </ul>
        </bs-navbar-dropdown>
    </div>
</bs-navbar>
```

No style at all will be applied, unless you disable view encapsulation. Furthermore, the navbar css will be produced 3 times still...

So ATM as far as I know, you'd be better off having the entire bootstrap.css once in your application, through your `angular.json` preferrably, (which can't be tree-shaken) than any of the above solutions...

As of your question about the replication of the bootstrap.css file, I created a blank angular app, installed `bootstrap`, and

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

in the `app.component.scss`

[image: Bundles after importing bootstrap in app.component.scss]

Then I generated another component, placed it on the appcomponent, and imported the entire bootstrap stylesheet here as well:

[image: Bundles after importing bootstrap in 2 components]

- (I would like to have a good solution for this too...)
- Don't accept this as answer pls.

Comment: Are you sure about the fact: "Importing bootstrap.css in each component that needs to be styled will cause the entire bootstrap css file to be replicated in the bundle for each component, while encapsulating the styles." You got any resource you can show me for this? I am new so I cant confirm or deny.

Comment: You know how view-encapsulation works right?